# Kubernetes creation in AWS - ap-northeast-2 region throws error "Please specify AWS_IMAGE directly (region not recognized)"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

Creating Kubernetes cluster in AWS cloud ap-northeast-2 region is throwing "Please specify AWS_IMAGE directly (region not recognized)" message.

Tried by setting the zone "export KUBE_AWS_ZONE="ap-northeast-2a"". But still fails to create.

```
[root@ip-172-31-29-160 cluster]# export KUBE_AWS_ZONE="ap-northeast-2a"
[root@ip-172-31-29-160 cluster]# ./kube-up.sh
*********************************************************
ZONE: ap-northeast-2a
REGION: ap-northeast-2
*********************************************************
... Starting cluster using provider: aws
... calling verify-prereqs
... calling kube-up
Starting cluster using os distro: vivid
Please specify AWS_IMAGE directly (region not recognized)
[root@ip-172-31-29-160 cluster]#
```

kubernetes/cluster/aws/config-default.sh

```
ZONE=${KUBE_AWS_ZONE:-ap-northeast-2a}
MASTER_SIZE=${MASTER_SIZE:-t2.large}
MINION_SIZE=${MINION_SIZE:-t2.large}
NUM_MINIONS=${NUM_MINIONS:-1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found this problem myself.....

Kubernetes creation in some AWS regions throwing error “Please specify AWS_IMAGE directly (region not recognized)”

Because some regions are not recognized by Kubernetes, so manually we need to export the image name.

```
export AWS_IMAGE=ami-a39oi23
```

Answer (score 0):

ap-northeast-2a is a zone not a region, the region id for Asia Pacific (Seoul) is ap-northeast-2. In order to specify the region, you need to set AWS_S3_REGION variable:

```
export AWS_S3_REGION=ap-northeast-2
```

Kubernetes guide for AWS: http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/

> Each region has multiple, isolated locations known as Availability
>   Zones. Amazon EC2 provides you the ability to place resources, such as
>   instances, and data in multiple locations. Resources aren't replicated
>   across regions unless you do so specifically.

More detail about regions and availability zones: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html

Comment: Actually kubernetes code itself converting the zone to region as by cutting the last digit(a).
For example : If we give like 
'export KUBE_AWS_ZONE="ap-northeast-2a"'
they handled the code to accept the region by removing the last digit as
"ap-northeast-2"
So only I printed 
**ZONE: ap-northeast-2a
REGION: ap-northeast-2**